# java convert string with units to integer

Tags: java

I want to convert strings like '1g' or '100k' or '15.3m' to integers. I suspect this is floating around some library in maven central, but I'm not quite sure where to look first.

To be clearer, I am concerned with dimensionless numbers, or, if you prefer, disk space / file size units. Think -Xmx to the java command.

Comment: Do you want the conversion to be unit aware?

Comment: He wants to know if the units should be kept: 1g = 9.81m\s² or if 1g=9.81 is sufficient.

Comment: @bmargulies - justkt's question means, for example: Should '100km' and '100m' both convert to 100? Or should the conversion be from kilometers or meters to some base unit of measure?

Comment: Why do you not use scientific notation like: "9.18E+09". If you need integers, then parse using double and cast it to integer.

Comment: I don't want physical units. I just want pure numbers. People are comfortable specifying 'amount of stuff' as 1gb, or 100mb (often with the b left off), I want to support that & I'm lazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JScience](http://jscience.org/) might be what you're looking for.

#### See also:

- [JavaWorld article on JSR-275 / JScience](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2007/jw-10-jsr275.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Units of Measure](http://code.google.com/p/unitsofmeasure/) library.  It's worked well for me in the past.

It's available using the [Maven Site](http://hudson.geomatys.com/job/Unit-API/ws/trunk/target/site/index.html) and via [Hudson CI Server](http://hudson.geomatys.com/job/Unit-API/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Any java library that conforms to [**JSR-275: Measures and Units**](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=275) is suitable. [JScience](http://jscience.org/) is one. [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2007/jw-10-jsr275.html) has an article on how JSR works.